# hardware recommendations for HAProxy for a small or medium traffic site

Tags: hardware, haproxy, linux, load-balancing

I am interested in setting up HAProxy for use as a load balancer for a set of small traffic web applications. The use is growing and might become medium sized in the near term (6 months or so). Mainly we are looking balance load becuase some customers want their own dedicated server, some what to be as low cost as possible so to accomodate we seem to need a load balancer.

I looked at the HAProxy home and some of the blogs but they really dont get into the specifics or are huge sites using sun servers for the application

What kind of hardware and which distrobution would anyone recommend in terms of processor, memory, storage and distrobution are you using or would recommend for such an application?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering that HAProxy is just modifying the header of each packet that goes thorough it, you need just a powerful CPU. I'm running a HAProxy for a large website on a 3GB DDR3, 7200rpm HDD SATA and a Xeon E5450. You need some bandwidth for this because all the traffic will go thorough this server (even if you are using nat or route)

Comment: so any modern core2 duo or quadcore should do the trick? and how much ram 2-4gb?

Comment: My Xeon is quad, but I never had the load on it higher than 50% (and this happened in peaks). I'm running with 3GB on DDR3 (on a HP DL360-G6) and I never had problems. I recommend you to make some graphs for the network traffic so you can detect networking bottlenecks.

Comment: A dual core is enough, neither haproxy nor the system will make use of the additional cores. But on a properly configured Core2duo 2.66 GHz, you can achieve up to about 40000 new connections per second, which it far more than enough for 99.99% of the web sites. Don't forget to put some RAM. With 4 GB you can support about 100000 concurrent connections. I strongly suggest that you install a 64-bit system. What bandwidth are you expecting to process ?

Comment: I'm considering this for my company's website. Any changes I should know about from the last 6.5 years?

Comment: not much, but please make sure you're not making this haproxy a single point of failure.. i would recommend having 2 or more loadbalancers (haproxy) in a pacemaker cluster

Answer (score 0):

The hardware requirements for HAProxy Enterprise depend on the workload it needs to manage:

[image]
See this link:

- https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/getting-started/hardware/